# Filter outliers with IQR and groupby in for loop, python

Tags: python, pandas, iqr

I would like to filter outliers by categories. For each column (fat_100g...) and each category from ['main_category_fr'] i would like to filter with the IQR method

My dataframe df :

[image]

I have done this :

```
nutriments = ["fat_100g", "carbohydrates_100g", "fiber_100g", "proteins_100g", "salt_100g", "sodium_100g","nutrition_score","sugars_100g","saturated-fat_100g"]

for var in nutriments:
    IQR = round(df[var].quantile(0.75) - df[var].quantile(0.25), 1)
    limite_haute = round(df[var].quantile(0.75) +(1.5 * IQR),1)
    df = df.loc[(df[var].isnull()) | (df[var] <=limite_haute)]
```

But i don't know how to use it for each category from ['main_category_fr'] in a loop

Comment: Please provide a sample as plain text. What do you expect as result. You cannot remove a row from a column without remove the entire row.

Comment: ...unless you make it NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion, you can use as starting point the code below.

What you need is to filter out all rows where all `nutriments` are not in their own interval defined by `iqr`

```
iqr = df[nutriments].apply(np.quantile, q=[0.25, 0.75])

out = df[((iqr.iloc[0] >= df[nutriments])
         & (df[nutriments] <= iqr.iloc[1])).all(axis=1)]
```